# Book recommendations for learning about open quantum systems

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, resource-recommendations, open-quantum-systems

Recently I'm curious about the topic of [open quantum system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_quantum_system) which is not talked about in common quantum mechanics textbooks, i.e. Master equation, Lindblad equation, reduced density matrix, entanglement entropy, correlation, decoherence, [Gleason's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gleason%27s_theorem), [Stinespring's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinespring_factorization_theorem#Application), [Completely Positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_positive_map)  and so on.

Are there some good references (easy and readable or rigorous and thorough) including papers, literatures or textbooks which can elucidate these topics related to open quantum systems?

Comment: This blog post is extremely helpful [Teaching /2: Open Quantum Systems for Ph. D. students](https://tomate.wordpress.com/2017/12/06/teaching-2-open-quantum-systems-for-ph-d-students/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A well-known reference for this is the book by Breuer and Petruccione:
[The theory of Open Quantum Systems](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198520638) (Oxford University Press; 1 edition (August 29, 2002)).  It seems to largely overlap with what you want.  It is well written and modern, covers the basic reasonably well if you have suitable background in statistics and in quantum mechanics, but does require some effort if you are self-teaching.